# Cookbook's deep dependency requires an unavailable Ruby version. How to circumvent via chef for Amazon Linux?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, aws-opsworks, cookbook

I'm a non-Ruby developer using Chef 11.10 on Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03, OpsWorks Agent v.3451.

My `Route53` [cookbook](https://github.com/chef-boneyard/route53/tree/v0.3.8) [requires](https://github.com/chef-boneyard/route53/blob/v0.3.8/recipes/default.rb#L49) `fog` which [requires](https://github.com/fog/fog/blob/master/fog.gemspec#L59) `fog-brightbox` which requires an [unspecified version](https://github.com/fog/fog-brightbox/blob/master/fog-brightbox.gemspec#L26) of `dry-inflector` whose [most recent version](https://github.com/dry-rb/dry-inflector/releases/tag/v0.2.0) [requires](https://github.com/dry-rb/dry-inflector/blob/master/dry-inflector.gemspec#L30) Ruby [version 2.4](https://github.com/dry-rb/dry-inflector/commit/f7255d6459b11f61ce10460d87286c08039af0ec) in its gemspec.

`fog` is installed via `chef_gem` which uses a [separate version of Ruby](https://docs.chef.io/resource_chef_gem.html) reserved for use by the Chef client only, and it is not recommended to update this Ruby version as it may [disable the Opsworks Agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workingcookbook-ruby.html).

Is the only way to get around this issue to fork and host each dependency in the chain, then force an earlier version of the deep dependency?

Comment: Version [`0.1.2` of the `dry-inflector` gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/dry-inflector/versions/0.1.2) doesn't require a specific version of ruby. Can you just ensure that that version is installed upfront?

Comment: This. I was installing after the dep gem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version [`0.1.2` of the `dry-inflector` gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/dry-inflector/versions/0.1.2) doesn't require a specific version of Ruby.

Just install the gem with that specific version as soon as possible on your machine.

Comment: I have inherited a large Chef deployment, and I have the problem that is described above. I don't understand how to install `dry-inflector` gem as soon as possible. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @RobWright I haven't worked with Chef in 6 years, so I don't have the exact syntax in my head. The idea is that with every Ruby installation, gems have to be installed, especially `bundler` will probably be installed somewhere in your recipe. Search for it and install the missing gem in the correct version directly in front of it in the same way.

Comment: Thanks. I'll dig in that direction.

Comment: @RobWright our route53 recipe does the installing: ```chef_gem "dry-inflector" do
     action :install
     version node['route53']['dry-inflector_version']
   end```. try searching for the `dry-inflector_version`